# How to iterate through all textblocks in a stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a stackpanel which has many textblocks added to it dynamically at runtime.  Whats the best way to change the font colour (to red) of the textblock which ive tapped, whilst ensuring all others are left as (or returned to) default white.

I already have the ontapped handler which changes the colour fine, but the problem arises when i then click a different/second textblock - as the initial one doesnt change back to white.
I think im looking for something along the lines of:

```
foreach (TextBlock tbl in MyStackPanel)
    {
        // change all text to white
    }

      // Get the tapped one and change it to red
```

However, you cant iterate through the stackpanel children as the compiler wont let you.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are they all direct children of `StackPanel` or nested in other controls?

Comment: You should using binding in order to change your TextBoxes color

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a `Children` property you can iterate through.

```
foreach (var tb in MyStackPanel.Children.OfType<TextBlock>())
    tb.Foreground = Brushes.White;
```